# Adding dynamically to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, fs

I have a json file that is generated dynamically by taking the values of a page using a crawler, json is created as follows:

```
{
"temperatura":"31°C",
"sensacao":"RealFeel® 36°",
"chuva":"0 mm",
"vento":"NNO11km/h",
"momentoAtualizacao":"Dia",
"Cidade":"carazinho",
"Site":"Accuweather"
}
{
"temperatura":"29 º",
"sensacao":"29º ST",
"vento":"11 Km/h",
"umidade":"51% UR",
"pressao":"1013 hPa",
"Cidade":"carazinho",
"Site":"Tempo Agora"
}
```

The problem with this generated file is missing [] to join all the files inside an array, and commas to separate the files.
The final json should look like this:

```
[{
    "temperatura":"31°C",
    "sensacao":"RealFeel® 36°",
    "chuva":"0 mm",
    "vento":"NNO11km/h",
    "momentoAtualizacao":"Dia",
    "Cidade":"carazinho",
    "Site":"Accuweather"
    },
    {
    "temperatura":"29 º",
    "sensacao":"29º ST",
    "vento":"11 Km/h",
    "umidade":"51% UR",
    "pressao":"1013 hPa",
    "Cidade":"carazinho",
    "Site":"Tempo Agora"
    }]
```

I am currently using this code to generate json.

```
const climatempo = async (config) => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    const override = Object.assign(page.viewport(), {width: 1920, heigth:1024});
    await page.setViewport(override);
    await page.goto(config.cidades[cidade],{waitUntil: 'load',timeout:'60000'})



    if(siteEscolhido == "accu"){
        const elementTemp = await page.$(config.regras.elementTemp)
        const temperatura = await page.evaluate(elementTemp => elementTemp.textContent, elementTemp)

        const sensacaoElement= await page.$(config.regras.sensacaoElement)
        const sensacao = await page.evaluate(sensacaoElement => sensacaoElement.textContent, sensacaoElement)

        const chuvaElement = await page.$(config.regras.chuvaElement)
        const chuva = await page.evaluate(chuvaElement => chuvaElement.textContent, chuvaElement)

        const ventoElement = await page.$(config.regras.ventoElement)
        const vento = await page.evaluate(ventoElement => ventoElement.textContent, ventoElement)

        const atualizadoA = await page.$(config.regras.atualizadoA)
        const momentoAtualizacao = await page.evaluate(atualizadoA => atualizadoA.textContent, atualizadoA)


        var dado = {
            temperatura:temperatura,
            sensacao:sensacao,
            chuva:chuva,
            vento:vento,
            momentoAtualizacao:momentoAtualizacao,
            Cidade:cidade,
            Site:"Accuweather"


        }
        //dados.push(dado)
        var x = JSON.stringify(dado)
        fs.appendFile('climatempo.json',x,function(err){
            if(err) throw err
        })


        console.log("Temperatura:" + temperatura)
        console.log(sensacao)
        console.log("Vento:" + vento)
        console.log("chuva:" + chuva)
        console.log(momentoAtualizacao)

        await browser.close()
```

If anyone has any idea how to solve my problem, please let me know!

Grateful, Carlos

Comment: unlike traditional modifying, in case of json you DON'T want to open and just append. You will want to open the file first take that content, append the new json content and replace the existing file's contents.

Comment: How big is this file going to get? If it's going to be hundreds or thousands of records, I disagree with the suggestions about parsing the entire file every single time just to add one record. But to each their own.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading the file, pushing onto an array captured from that file, and then writing the file back to disk.

Assuming the file has content already in the form of an array:

```
let fileDado = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('climatempo.json'));

fileDado.push(dado);

fs.writeFileSync('climatempo.json', JSON.stringify(fileDado));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it a little differently

I will try to explain in pseudo code since i dont understand your variable names

1. read json file
2. array = JSON.parse(fileContents)
3. array.push(newItem)
4. newContents = JSON.stringify(array)
5. file WRITE (not append) newContents